# Similar functionality for string uniqueness in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

my question is is there any way to do this functionality in mySQL:
`$str = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $str)));` . 
Since I am doing a table update in a loop, i need to check if the string already exists in the column. Something like

```
Item | Numbers
A    | 1,2,4
B    | 6,7,8
C    | 2,7,5
```

So if an entry comes in which should be added to row B, say 7,8,30 it should only add 30 in the string. so B | 6,7,8,30.
I know about selecting the row first and doing it in PHP, I am looking for a way to do directly in mySQL.

Note : Unfortunately I wont be able to change the table structure. (Edited)

Thanks

Comment: I would highly consider normalizing your data.  Consider creating an Item_Numbers table where you store a single item and a single number (allows you the ability to store 1-n numbers associated with an item).  If you can't change you're data, you can look into creating a Split function to split comma delimited data (search SO for examples).

Answer (score 0):

If you had your table in a correct format, then yes. You would need `Item` to be a key, `Number` to be a numeric column, and `Item,Number` to be the primary key. Then you can do this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES ('B',7), ('B',8), ('B',30)
```

This will ignore duplicates when adding values. When it comes to getting the data back, you can simply get all rows where `Item='B'` and implode them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
update t
    set Numbers = (case when Numbers = '' then '30'
                        else concat(Numbers, ',', 30)
                   end)
    where item = 'B';
```

However, the data structure is not very good for what you want to accomplish.  You should have a table called `ItemNumbers`, which would have an item and a number in each row.